# MongoDB inserting multiple documents where duplicate _id is possible

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb, error-handling

I'm using the following to insert an array of objects into a MongoDB(I'm assigning a unique _id), which is working:

```
collection.insert(records, {w:1}, function(err, result)
```

It's possible that some of the records could have a duplicate _id(meaning that record is already in the DB). Here is the error I get:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: heroku_app23495772.records.$_id_  dup key: { : "2b09aadb900f0e5112b6d03f665fb946" }
```

Will mongoDB still insert remaining objects in this array even after encountering the error on the first object(duplicate)? I really don't mind the error if it it won't prevent remaining documents that are not duplicates from being inserted or affect anything else negatively.

Or, should I literally query the DB for each object to see if it exists before sending the array of objects? I would think doing that would not be the best thing for performance.

I'm just trying to figure out the most efficient way of dealing with these duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I finally got this to work. Including `continueOnError: true` will continue inserting the rest of the batch even if some are not inserted because they are duplicates.

```
collection.insert(records, {continueOnError: true}, function(err, result) {
```

Comment: Might want to add {  keepGoing:true } if { continueOnError:true } by itself doesnt work(as it wasnt for me). The end results would simply be  {  keepGoing: true, continueOnError: true }

Answer (score 0):

The **_id** must be unique in the collection, so you cannot insert 2 documents with the same _id.

Not sure what is your exact use case but you have another approach, such as doing an upsert or save.

If you do a collection.save the document will be replaced:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/

If you do an update, with the upsert:true you can control what needs to be updated or created:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists-upsert

If this does not help, can you please give us the exact use case you are trying to achieve, and remember that if you do not provide any _id the system will generate one for you.